# Solve for unknown matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
4 & 5        
\end{bmatrix}$
and let $B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6        
\end{bmatrix}$
Solve $A X = B$ for a matrix $X$

My guess is that i:

let $X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y        
\end{bmatrix}$

Then solve it using a linear equation but i'm not too sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply $A^{-1}$ to the left of each side

Comment: This is mathematics: there's no room for "guessing" unless *later* you prove/verify your guessing was correct

Comment: Hint: the product of two matrices can be seen as independent products of the first matrix by the columns of the second.

Comment: @Coolwater That would remove A, correct?

Answer (score 5):

Let

$$X=\left[\begin{matrix} a &b\\ c &d\end{matrix}\right].$$

Expanding the matrix product, you need to solve

$$\begin{cases}2a+3c=3\\4a+5c=5\\2b+3d=4\\4b+5d=6\end{cases}$$

**Hint**:
$$\begin{cases}2a+3c=3\\4a+5c=5\end{cases}$$ $$\begin{cases}2b+3d=4\\4b+5d=6\end{cases}$$

---

The real, efficient method is by solving the system (by Gaussian elimination) for all right-hand sides *simultaneously*.

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}2x+3y=3|4\\4x+5y=5|6\end{align}\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}2x+3y=\ \ \ 3|\ \ \ \ \ 4\\0x-1y=-1|-2\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}2x+0y=\ \ \ 0|-2\\0x-1y=-1|-2\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}x=0|-1\\y=1|\ \ \ \ \ 2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is there a canonical source that shows how to do this? All the Gaussian elimination tutorials I've found solve for vector unknowns (e.g, Ax=b <-> solve(A,b)), not matrix unknowns (AX=B <-> solve(A,B)).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Think about inverting Matrix A and rewriting it as $X=A^{-1}B$. The inverse of a 2 by 2 matrix is simple to generate by hand. Your approach is the right one but you will have to introduce a 2 by 2 matrix for $X$ instead of a vector.

Comment: So i multiply both sides by the inverse of A thus removing A, then multiply the inverse of A with B to get X?

Comment: Yes. Or you can solve the system that you proposed. In numerical computation one would rather use your approach, but for calculations by hand I would suggest to use the invers for a 2 by 2 matrix.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to multiply $2\times 2$ matrix with $2\times 1$ matrix and give a $2\times 2$ matrix.
But if in your question $B$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix, you can solve this system of equation by [elimination](https://www.google.com/search?q=triangular+representatio&rlz=1C1GGGE___IR597IR597&oq=triangular+representatio&aqs=chrome..69i57.365j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=solve+this+system+of+equation+by+elimination):
$$\begin{cases}2x+3y=a\\4x+5y=b\end{cases}$$